# How can I make a string contain filter on Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to make a string contain filter in Neo4J. The idea is simple.

A good example is that I need to retrieve from a database of persons all the people that contain  in his name the car substring.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to match a part of a name, for example:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ '.*car.*'
RETURN n
```

If you have the label 'Person' assigned to all people in your database, the query would be:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE n.name =~ '.*car.*'
RETURN n
```

For further information, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-where.html#_regular_expressions

Answer (score 33):

As an additional update, from neo4j 3.0 it may be more readable to use:

```
MATCH(n)
WHERE n.name CONTAINS 'car'
RETURN n
```

(Edited to include [Maciej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600775/maciej) fix to my response, thank you!)

Comment: This approach works but you must surround car in quotes like so: MATCH(n) WHERE n.name CONTAINS 'car' RETURN n

Comment: Can you use contains with a list of words?