# is there any way in Neo4J using CONTAINS to compare case-insensitive string?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose there is a node, `Student`, that has a property `Name`.

```
MATCH (s:Student) were s.Name contains "stack" 
RETURN s.Name
```

the output should be like : stack, Stack, STACK etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a string contain filter on Neo4j Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094882/how-can-i-make-a-string-contain-filter-on-neo4j-cypher)

Comment: Seriously, I mean just google Neo4j and contains, it's right there infront of you...Not to mention the duplicate suggestions when you asked the question or the links to the right of this very question.

Comment: He is after a more specific use case - he wants `CONTAINS` to work without case sensitivity but it is case insensitive. Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250810/neo4j-order-by-relevance#44250930 where somebody wanted to search on a value with CONTAINS but have it match all cases of that value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can make the comparison on the upper/lower case version of each, for example:

```
MATCH (s:Student) 
WHERE toLower(s.Name) CONTAINS toLower("stack")
RETURN s.Name
```

Comment: Disadvantage - If you add toLower() it will not apply Index. :-(

Comment: we are trying to use [full text search index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-full-text-search/) to sovle the above problem, 
see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76372597/how-to-apply-a-full-text-search-index-on-an-exiting-neo4j-query/76372727#76372727)

Answer (score 10):

The regular expression operator, `=~`, supports case insensitive searches via the `(?i)` modifier.

This query is the equivalent of yours, except it is case insensitive:

```
MATCH (s:Student)
WHERE s.Name =~ '(?i).*stack.*'
RETURN s.Name
```

Comment: Disadvantage of this is - Its doesn't apply Index.