# How to efficiently use a fulltext index to search based on prior MATCH results in same query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### Intro

This what an existing query of mine looks like:

```
MATCH
(p:Person { id: $p_id })-[k1:`KNOWS`]->(person:Person)
WHERE (// some criteria)
MATCH
(person)-[work:`WORKED_AT`]->(company:Company)
WHERE (work.title contains “Product Manager" and work.start_date is not null)
WITH person, work
RETURN
DISTINCT person.full_name, work.title
```

The problem in the above query is that it is not case insensitive. So the above query fails if the actual title is `product manager` in the database.

So we are trying to use [full text search index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-full-text-search/). We created the index on the `:work` relationship, and we verified that it works, for example the search of:

```
call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships(“<indexName>”, “CEO”) 
yield relationship return reltionship.title limit 10
```

would return stuff like:

```
CEO
Ceo
..etc
```

### Question

How can I apply the above index search on the node search? For example:

```
MATCH
(p:Person { id: $p_id })-[k1:`KNOWS`]->(person:Person)
WHERE (// some criteria)
MATCH
(person)-[work:`WORKED_AT`]->(company:Company)
WHERE //apply the db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships here on :work somehow
WITH person, work
RETURN
DISTINCT person.full_name, work.title
```

Comment: If you're correcting for case sensitivity, why not just use `toLower(work.title) contains "product manager"`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll first have to fetch the relationships using the index and then apply the `MATCH`. Try this:

```
MATCH (p:Person { id: $p_id })-[k1:`KNOWS`]->(person:Person)
WHERE (// some criteria)
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("indexName", "searchString") 
YIELD relationship AS work
MATCH (person)-[work]->(company:Company)
WITH person, work
RETURN DISTINCT person.full_name, work.title
```

Alternatively, you can perform a case-insensitive search using regex. Like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person { id: $p_id })-[k1:`KNOWS`]->(person:Person)
WHERE (// some criteria)
MATCH (person)-[work:`WORKED_AT`]->(company:Company)
WHERE (work.title =~ '(?i).*Product Manager.*' and work.start_date is not null)
WITH person, work
RETURN DISTINCT person.full_name, work.title
```

Comment: I already tried that version, the problem is that it searches through _all_ indexes which takes forever. I want it to only search through the relationships that exist in the original query

Comment: Got it. I have updated the answer to perform a case-insensitive search using regex. I don't think we can restrict the number of relationships to be searched in the full-text index. A workaround needs to be created. @abbood

Comment: I thought of regex too. The problem is that we have millions of titles and so using the index on the title is very important. Using regex will [invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212213/is-there-any-way-in-neo4j-using-contains-to-compare-case-insensitive-string#comment84321912_45222229) the index and thus make the above search prohibitively slow..

Comment: actually your regex answer seems to work pretty fast, that's strange, does it really invalidate the index or not? it cannot be that fast if it's not using the index 

Comment: The index will not be used as far as I know. You can confirm it by adding `PROFILE` in front of the query and checking the execution stats. `FULLTEXT` index is only used by the `db.index.fulltext.query*` functions. It's fast because the total number of relationships being fetched and checked is too small.

Comment: What is the speed of this query `call db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships(“<indexName>”, “CEO”) 
yield relationship return reltionship.title limit 10` without limit?